# How can I get a base64 encoded shaX on the cli?

Tags: hashsum, cryptography, base64

`sha1sum` outputs a hex encoded format of the actual sha. I would like to see a base64 encoded variant. possibly some command that outputs the binary version that I can pipe, like so: `echo -n "message" | <some command> | base64` or if it outputs it directly that's fine too.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you have the command line utility from [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), it can produce a digest in binary form, and it can even translate to base64 (in a separate invocation).

```
printf %s foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64 -A
```

`-sha256`, `-sha512`, etc are also supported.

Comment: `echo foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | base64` is equivalent, and probably the cleanest way of doing this.

Comment: Using `openssl` for base64 as well has the advantage of depending on only one tool (`ksh: base64: not found`).

Comment: For large message digest hashes like `sha512`, you might want to add `-A` option to the final `openssl base64` command, to prevent splitting the resulting string into multiple lines.

Comment: @Gilles Why `echo foo > somefile; cat somefile | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64` produces a different string?

Comment: @gliatsos Because `echo -n foo` and `echo foo` produce different strings.

Comment: Yes, please remember the `-n` flag. I just spent two days debugging why my credentials were invalid. The hash was not what I thought it was XD

Answer (score 31):

Since `sha1sum` doesn't provide an option for binary output you'll likely need to find an utility which does the opposite of `od` and pipe them.  Taking suggestion by fschmitt to use `xxd` with 'reverse' and 'plain dump' flags it will look like this:

`sha1sum | cut -f1 -d\  | xxd -r -p | base64`

Comment: awesome! This was hard to figure out from the documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html which dont mention the necessarity of this step

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you want, but I think something like the following should work:

```
$ echo -ne "$(echo -n "message" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d" " | sed -e 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\\x\1/g')" | base64
```

Basically, I take the hex output, use `sed` to make it a string of escaped hex values, and then use `echo -en` to echo the bytes into `base64`.

We can confirm that the final output corresponds to the same hash with the following exercise:

```
$ echo -n "message" | sha1sum 
6f9b9af3cd6e8b8a73c2cdced37fe9f59226e27d  -

$ echo -ne "$(echo -n "message" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d" " | sed -e 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\\x\1/g')" | base64
b5ua881ui4pzws3O03/p9ZIm4n0=

$ echo -n "b5ua881ui4pzws3O03/p9ZIm4n0=" | base64 -d | xxd
0000000: 6f9b 9af3 cd6e 8b8a 73c2 cdce d37f e9f5  o....n..s.......
0000010: 9226 e27d                                .&.}
```

Visual inspection shows that our base64 value matches the original hex.  Note that if you use `hexdump` rather than `xxd` you may have to play with the format settings a bit to get the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a base64 module (in the base distribution since 5.7.1).

```
echo foo | sha1sum | \
perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne '/^([[:xdigit:]]+)/ and print encode_base64(pack("H*",$1))'
```

If you have the `Digest::SHA` module (in the base distribution since 5.9.3), or the older `Digest::SHA1` module, you can do the whole computation in perl. As of perl 5.10.1, `b64digest` doesn't pad the base64 output; if you need padding the easiest way is to use `MIME::Base64`.

```
perl -MDigest::SHA -e 'print Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile(*STDIN)->b64digest'
perl -MMIME::Base64 -MDigest::SHA \
     -le 'print encode_base64(Digest::SHA->new(1)->addfile(*STDIN)->digest)'
```

Comment: well if we're using perl, we could just use the Digest::SHA module which would allow us to output directly to base64.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoded SHA256 hash became rather standard file checksum in **OpenBSD** recently..
It can be done just with adding `-b` option to the OpenBSD's `sha256` (or sha1, sha512) command:

```
$ FILE=/dev/null
$ sha256 -q -b $FILE
47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
```

or:

```
$ cksum -q -a sha256b $FILE
```