# How can I decrypt back a base64 encoded shaX binary string?

Tags: command-line, openssl, hashsum, base64

For the [encrypted base64 encoded SHAX strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3713/72456), what command can decrypt it back to original string, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked post, your original string was generated by a method such as

```
echo -n foo | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64
```

What this generates is a *digest*, with SHA1 being the method of calculating the digest.

In this situation there is insufficient data to reconstruct the original string.  This digest is a *checksum* of the original string and can be used for validation; to verify a message hasn't been tampered with.

So if you have a file `xyzzy` that contains your message you can run

```
cat xyzzy | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64
```

If the result is the same string as you started with then you can be confident it hasn't been modified.

The best you can do is remove the `base64` part to get the binary digest:

```
echo $base64string | openssl base64 -d
```

but this is *not* the original message, just the checksum.  The original message is *not* reconstructable from the digest.